# mysql recursive query from node of interest to root node

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

**I have a mysql table as follows:**

```
id | name        | parent_id
19 | category1   | NULL
20 | category2   | 19
21 | category3   | 20
22 | category4   | 21
```

How do i write a recursive mysql query to fetch all the nodes from input node to root node.
E.g: If the input is category3, the output should be category3, category2 and category1

Answer (score 0):

We can try using the following recursive hierarchical query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (id, name, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT     id,
               name,
               parent_id
    FROM       yourTable
    WHERE      parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     p.id,
               p.name,
               p.parent_id
    FROM       yourTable p
    INNER JOIN cte
            ON p.parent_id = cte.id
    WHERE      cte.name <> 'category3'
)

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY id DESC) AS names FROM cte;
```

This outputs:

```
category3,category2,category1
```

### Demo

The idea here is to short circuit the recursions to stop at the point where the parent would be `category3`.  If the recursive portion of the CTE hits this point, it means that it already one step *below* the `category3` level, and so should stop.